# Why bot doesn't fire messageReactionAdd event when the message was sent before the bot was online

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

This is my event to check user add react:

```js
const client = require("../index");

client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
    if (user.bot) return;
    console.log(reaction.emoji.name);
});
```

It's working, but when the bot restarts, it can't fetch any message sent before?

Why and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need [partials:](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/partials.html#enabling-partials)

```js
const client = new Client({
    intents: ‘’, // your intents here
    partials: ['CHANNEL', 'GUILD_MEMBER', 'GUILD_SCHEDULED_EVENT', 'MESSAGE', 'REACTION', 'USER'],
});
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't enable partial structures, your code only works on cached messages; ones posted after the bot is connected. Reacting on older messages won't fire the `messageReactionAdd` event.

If you also want to listen to reactions on old messages you need to enable partial structures for `MESSAGE`, `CHANNEL` and `REACTION` when instantiating your client, like this:

```js
const { Client, Intents } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Discord.Client({
  intents: [
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES,
    Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS,
  ],
  partials: ['CHANNEL', 'GUILD_MEMBER', 'MESSAGE', 'REACTION', 'USER'],
});
```

If you're using discord.js v14, you can use enums like this:

```js
const { Client, GatewayIntentBits, Partials } = require('discord.js');

const client = new Client({
  intents: [
    GatewayIntentBits.Guilds,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMember,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages,
    GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessageReactions,
    GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent,
  ],
  partials: [Partials.Channel, Partials.Message, Partials.Reaction],
});
```