# Obtening reactions in discord js 13 not working

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to create a bot for my-self that count reactions but when i try using this code to obtain all reactions it doesnt work at all. If any of you have an idea.

```
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    console.log(reaction.emoji.name); 
})
```

I tried placing emojis and all but it never printed anything.

Comment: Do you have any errors? Do you have the correct intents enabled?

Comment: No error nothing logged, and i have these intents : GUILDS, GUILD_MESSAGE

Comment: @HarryAllen (forgot to tag you)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why bot doesn't fire messageReactionAdd event when the message was sent before the bot was online](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71950399/why-bot-doesnt-fire-messagereactionadd-event-when-the-message-was-sent-before-t)