# Discord.js How to access the message using messageReactionAdd

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I currently have this function in my bot that triggers every time a message is reacted to:

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', (reaction, user) => {
    if(reaction.emoji.id === "1014887969808711800") {
        if (user.username !== 'IteroBetBot') {
            console.log('Fnatic');
            voterArray1.push(user.username);
        }
    } else if (reaction.emoji.id === "1065285604578959430") {
        if (user.username !== 'IteroBetBot') {
            console.log('Koi');
            voterArray2.push(user.username);
        }
    }
     else if (reaction.emoji.name === '') {
         console.log('Found it');
         let finalString1 = '';
         let finalString2 = '';
         voterArray1.forEach(element => {
             finalString1 += element + " "
         });
         voterArray2.forEach(element => {
            finalString2 += element + " "
        });
        finalString1 += ' voted for Fnatic';
        finalString2 += ' voted for Koi';
        client.channels.cache.get('1077613044563202058').send(finalString1);
        client.channels.cache.get('1077613044563202058').send(finalString2);
    }
});
```

I need to be able to access the message that was reacted to in order to check if the stop emoji already exists on the message.

How could I access the message `messageReactionAdd` was called on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter, `reaction` has a [`message`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=message) property. That's the message that the reaction refers to.

Make sure you have the correct `intents` and `partials` if you want to get reactions on older messages. If you don't enable partial structures, your code only works on cached messages; ones posted after the bot is connected. Reacting on older messages won't fire the messageReactionAdd event: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71950603/6126373

Comment: Thank you very much for this. Do you by chance also know how to check if a message has a specific reaction? I have tried this ````!!reaction.message?.reactions.cache.find(v => v.name === '')```` but it always returns false even when that emoji is present.

Comment: You're welcome. I think that should be `!!reaction.message?.reactions.cache.find(v => v.emoji.name === '')`.

Answer (score 1):

You'd use `reaction.message`

[Docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/discord.js/main/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=message)